# ng-show is not working for one of the similar input fields

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-validation

I have a multistep form. I have ng-show which depends whether or not the input[type="text"] is empty.

Now, it works for one section of the form, but doesn't work for another section of the form.

```
<div id="wrapper-signup">
  <h1>Borrower Signup</h1>
  <p>Register and start borrowing money online.</p>

  <div class="element-wrap">
    <label>NAME<br>
      <div class="name-wrap">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newuser.firstname" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newuser.lastname" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
      <p class="error" style="width: 45%; color: red; font-size: 0.9em; clear: both; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" ng-show="signForm.firstname.$dirty && newuser.firstname.length ===  0">Firstname required</p>
      <p class="error" style="width: 45%; color: red; font-size: 0.9em; clear: both; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" ng-show="signForm.lastname.$dirty && newuser.lastname.length ===  0">Lastname required</p>
    </label><br>
  </div>
  <div class="element-wrap">
      <label for="email">EMAIL
        <div class="email-num-wrap">
          <span class="awesome-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg email-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><input type="email" id="email" ng-model="newuser.email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email ID" required>
        </div>
        <p class="error" style="color: red; font-size: 0.9em;" ng-show="signForm.email.$invalid && signForm.email.$dirty">Enter a valid email</p>
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="element-wrap">
    <label>MOBILE NUMBER
      <div class="email-num-wrap">
        <span class="awesome-icon"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-lg mobile-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><input type="number" id="number" ng-model="newuser.number" name="mobile" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength ="10" value="" placeholder="Enter 10 digit number" required>
      </div>
      <p class="error" style="color: red; font-size: 1em;" ng-show="signForm.mobile.$dirty && (signForm.mobile.$error.minlength || singForm.mobile.$error.maxlength)">Please enter a 10 digit number</p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="clear">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="terms" value="" ng-model="tcheck" required><p class="checkbox-text">I have read and agree to the <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>, <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> and consent to Electronic Disclosures.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="condiiton" value="" ng-model="ccheck" required><p class="checkbox-text">I authorize RupaiyaExchange to share my details with other Financial Institutions for credit card check and faster processing of loan.</p>
  </div>
  <a ui-sref='index.otp' ng-show="signForm.email.$valid && tcheck && ccheck && signForm.mobile.$valid && newuser.firstname.length !== 0 && newuser.lastname.length !==  0 " class="submit-signup">SIGNUP</a>

</div>
```

It works for above view, but doesn't work for below view

```
<div id="wrapper-identity">
    <p>Please enter the following details</p>
    <div class="aadhar-wrap">
        <label for="aadhar">Aadhar Card</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="aadhar" ng-model="newuser.aadhar" id="aadharN" value="" placeholder="Enter Aadhar Card No" required>
        <p class="error" style="color: red; font-size: 0.9em; clear: both; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" ng-show="signForm.aadhar.$dirty && newuser.aadhar.length === 0">Aadhar number required</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pan-wrap">
        <label for="pan">PAN</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="pan" ng-model="newuser.pan" value="" id="panN" placeholder="Enter PAN No" required>
        <p class="error" style="color: red; font-size: 0.9em; clear: both; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" ng-show="signForm.pan.$dirty && newuser.pan.length === 0">PAN number required</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" ng-hide="signForm.aadhar.$dirty && newuser.pan.length === 0 && signForm.pan.$dirty && newuser.aadhar.length === 0" ng-click="go('/index/done')" name="submit-info" value="Submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

I don't want to populate this place, since the css file is very large.

Here's the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/PEhGJ50XGjYxQcetTxNV?p=preview

Comment: Running your plnkr, I am seeing the aadhar card/pam form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not check for length rather check for the value newuser.pan

```
<p class="error" style="color: red; font-size: 0.9em; clear: both; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" ng-show="signForm.aadhar.$dirty && !newuser.aadhar">Aadhar number required</p>

<p class="error" style="color: red; font-size: 0.9em; clear: both; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" ng-show="signForm.pan.$dirty && !newuser.pan">PAN number required</p>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. This worked, but why didn't it work when I checked the length. Because it worked for the Firstname and Lastname in the signup.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to investigate the values returned by each condition in each situation.

For example, try to use this in your partial:

```
<p>
DEBUG: {{ signForm.aadhar.$dirty }} && {{ newuser.pan.length === 0 }} && {{ signForm.pan.$dirty }} && {{ newuser.aadhar.length === 0 }}
</p>
```

Comment: hey, I was checking the values and an interesting thing happened. boolean values for length were initially false, when the user starts typing, it changes to true, but when the user clears the field it remains true. Could you explain why?

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is related to the fact that the field has undefined content at first. When the user starts typing and later clears the field, it becomes an empty string.

Comment: but i had used ```===``` and empty string should yield false

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the ng-hide expression. You should use ng-show, also inverting the length controls:

```
 <input type="submit" ng-show="signForm.aadhar.$dirty && newuser.pan.length != 0 && signForm.pan.$dirty && newuser.aadhar.length != 0" ng-click="go('/index/done')" name="submit-info" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

It controls if both of the inputs have been changed an there is some value in them. If the condition holds, Submit button appears, otherwise it's hidden.